# Thread.Start() Does not start a thread in xamarin

Tags: c#, ios, multithreading, xamarin.ios

I have a project in Xamarin.IOS which interacts with a UI component via NSEvents. UI sends messages through events with a payload - google's `protobuf` encoded objects. UI is written in ObjC, the logic is written in C#.

Each `NSEvent` is caught in an observer that invokes internal logic which begins the processing of a message. These messages are put into a queue and eventually taken by threads from the queue.

When a message arrives, the program can create a thread for it, and that's the place where it fails. The code is legacy, so we are using `Thread`. I write

```
Thread t = new Thread(ThreadProc);
t.IsBackground = true;
t.Start();
```

The code *used to* work a short while ago, also it works *sometimes*. Sometimes the thread is simply not created. No error is reported.

If I create a thread not in a context of an observer, the thread is started.

I have no idea why it may happen. The problem arises in the very initialization of the application, when the first thread is about to be created. So I don't think there are too many threads.

I have tried to re-create it with `Task` interface. Tasks are created and started alright, but I can not migrate entire solution to `Task`s, unfortunately.

I guess there is some configuration issue or like that since it used to work. I just don't get what it might be. What can affect `Thread.Start()`?

**UPD:** I've rolled back to a very old commit which used to work, now it fails too. So it seems not to be a configuration issue, but ios/xamarin issue.

Answer (score 1):

I've never seen anything remotely similar (creating and starting a Thread not actually doing anything), so my first thought is to ensure that this code is actually executed in the first place.

Can you add a Console.WriteLine statements like this:

```
Console.WriteLine ("creating thread");
Thread t = new Thread(() =>
{
    Console.WriteLine ("executing ThreadProc");
    try {
        ThreadProc ();
    } finally {
        Console.WriteLine ("finished executing ThreadProc");
    }
});
t.IsBackground = true;
t.Start();
Console.WriteLine ("started thread");
```

and then see what actually shows up in the application output?

Comment: Sure. `2015-01-22 16:07:17.064 STA[699:295687] creating thread   
2015-01-22 16:07:17.066 STA[699:295687] started thread`

Comment: Then I suggest you file a bug (http://bugzilla.xamarin.com) with your project so that we can look at it.

Comment: @RolfBjarneKvinge I have seen two instances of this recently in a mature production app.  Each time, the background Tasks do not start (nothing written to my own log when normally they are).  Once the iPad is restarted, all is well again. Never seen anything like it before.  From what I can see, it isn't running out of memory.  It is an iPad Air running iOS 9.1.  Can't see any bugs logged in Bugzilla.  Don't know how to even report this.

Comment: @joehanna: is it enough to restart the app to fix the issue, or do you have to restart the entire iPad?